# Gateway Timeout после создания Zip-файла

Tags: php, foreach, ziparchive

Создаю zip-файл с помощью ZipArchive, куда записываю изображения. Процесс довольно долгий, но VPS позволяет.

```
  $zip = new ZipArchive();
  $imagesZipFile = __DIR__.'/../files/images_' . $xmlCreateDatetime . '.zip';
  $imageNewName = 'autocity_'.$car['id'];

  $i = 0;
  foreach($imagesArray as $image){
    if($image != '..' AND $image != '.'):
      // Add image to zip
      if($zip->open($imagesZipFile, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE):
        continue;
      endif;
      $zip->addFile($imageDir . '/' . $image, $imageNewName.$image);

      // Add string to xml
      $ImageElt  = $domDoc->createElement('Image');
      $ImageName = $domDoc->createAttribute('name');
      $ImageName->appendChild($domDoc->createTextNode($imageNewName.$image));
      $ImageElt->appendChild($ImageName);
      $ImagesNode->appendChild($ImageElt);
      $i++;
    endif;
  }
  $zip->close();
```

В итоге файл полностью создается, помещается в нужную папку, но в конце скрипт отдает Gateway Timeout, хотя при небольших циклах возвращает нужную переменную.

В итоге два вопроса:

1. Возможно ли как-то облегчить процесс создания архива (может быть очистка памяти или что-нибудь подобное)
2. Можно ли избежать 504-ой ошибки и если можно, то как?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас fast-cgi + php-fpm на сервере, то можно использовать функцию `fastcgi_finish_request();` она отдает ответ браузеру, при этом скрипт продолжает выполняться на сервере, периодически записывая куда-то состояние выполнения задачи

Comment: Установил php-fpm на сервере (`sudo apt-get install php-fpm`), но функция отрабатывать не хочет почему-то (undefined). Версия php 5.4 (изменить не могу, тут же крутится сервис, который при изменении версии может рухнуть).